# A woman paid a $\$9.75$ debt using only dimes and quarters. In how many ways is this possible?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I am trying to solve this in my numbers theory class. I have no issues finding the gcd of $5$, but I have been having issues with working backwards to find $x$ and $y$ so I can find $t$. To tell the truth, I have an issue with completing the process using the Euclidean Algorithm to find $x$ and $y$. If I can get help finding $x$ and $y$, I am confident that I can do the rest.

Comment: $39$ quarters will do it, and then you can exchange two quarters for five dimes, and then exchange another two quarters for five dimes, and then again. Ask yourself how many times that can be done.

Answer (score 2):

So basically your problem is to find number of possible solutions of the equation

$9.75 = 0.1x + 0.25y$ where $x$ is number of dimes and $y$ is number of quarters.

Multiplying by 100 and dividing by $5$ (or multiplying by $20$) on both sides, we have

$$195 = 2x + 5y$$

$$x = \frac{5(39-y)}{2}$$

So here we see that for x to be an integer, $y$ should be odd.

Hence possible values of $y$ are $1,3,5,7,\ldots,39$.
Correspondingly calculate $x.$

So there are $20$ solutions or $20$ possible ways to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. It was a "I should have had a V8" moment for me.